# Unsatisfied exceptions while creating beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Please help. I am trying to create first Spring boot application and getting following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DepartmentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Departments
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.demo.EmployeersbootApplication.main(EmployeersbootApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DepartmentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Departments
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DepartmentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Departments
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Departments
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:228) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code of my main class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controller")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.services")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.repository")

public class EmployeersbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeersbootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the controller is:

```
package com.example.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.example.model.Departments;
import com.example.services.DepartmentsService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/department")
@SpringBootApplication

public class DepartmentsController {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentsService departmentsService;
    
     @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView list()
     {
         ModelAndView model=new  ModelAndView("departments_list");
         List<Departments> departmentsList=departmentsService.getAllDepartments();
          model.addObject("departmentsList", departmentsList);
          return model;

     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/adddepartment/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    
     public ModelAndView addDepartment()
     {
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView();
        Departments departments= new Departments();
        model.addObject("departmentsForm", departments);
        model.setViewName("departments_form");
        return model;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/editdepartment/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    
     public ModelAndView editDepartment(@PathVariable int id)
     {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
          Departments departments = departmentsService.getDepartmentById(id);
          model.addObject("departmentsForm", departments);
            model.setViewName("departments_form");
            return model;
     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/adddepartment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("departmentsForm") Departments departments)
     {
        departmentsService.addDepartment(departments);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/department/list");
         
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/deletedepartment/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") int id)
     {
         departmentsService.deleteDepartment(id);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/department/list");
         
     }

}
```

The service interface

```
package com.example.services;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.example.model.Departments;

public interface DepartmentsService {

public List<Departments> getAllDepartments();
public Departments getDepartmentById(int id);
public void addDepartment(Departments department);
public void deleteDepartment(int id);

}
```

And the implementation is

```
package com.example.services;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.model.Departments;
import com.example.repository.DepartmentsRepository;

@Service
@Transactional

public class DepartmentsServiceImplementation implements DepartmentsService {

    @Autowired
    DepartmentsRepository departmentsRepository;
    
    @Override
    public List<Departments> getAllDepartments() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<Departments>) departmentsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Departments getDepartmentById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return departmentsRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void addDepartment(Departments department) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        departmentsRepository.save(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDepartment(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        departmentsRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

The repository:

```
package com.example.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.model.Departments;
@Repository
public interface DepartmentsRepository extends CrudRepository<Departments, Integer> {

}
```

Enteti class:

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")

public class Departments {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


    

}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix the problem? Sorry if I am duplication the question.

Comment: Try adding `@EntityScan("com.example.model.*")` on `EmployeersbootApplication`.

Comment: In addition to what @sp00m wrote, please also post your `Department` entity class. Is it annotated with `@Entity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have structured your project differently. Normally the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` should be in the base package compare to other packages. Seems like issue `Spring` cannot find the entity class for component scan.

I can see your `EmployeersbootApplication` class package is `com.example.demo`. The easiest fix is move this class to `com.example` from `com.example.demo`. If you do that I believe you will no longer need following annotation in your `EmployeersbootApplication` class.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controller")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.services")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controller")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.services")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
```

To

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
```

That way you will scan all packages within example package with single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Having said that, do the following changes in `EmployeersbootApplication` (remove the `@ComponentScan` annotations and move it to the package `com.example`):

```java
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
public class EmployeersbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeersbootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In addition, remove `@SpringBootApplication` from `DepartmentsController` as follows:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/department")
public class DepartmentsController {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentsService departmentsService;
    
    (...)  // Your endpoint here
}
```